# Erro de login com Google firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase, login

sou novo em programação Android e ficaria grato se vocês conseguissem mim ajudar. Fiz um app que utiliza login com Google firebase, funciona perfeitamente quando executo diretamente no celular mas quando gero o APK assinado e coloco no teste interno da play store ele não faz login. Acredito que não seja erro no código pois está funcionando fora da play store, talvez seja alguma configuração no firebase ou no teste interno ou algum outro que eu não sei. Se algum de vocês já passaram por isso por favor mim ajudem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será necessário obter o SHA-1 do certificado usado para assinar o seu aplicativo publicado na Play Store e depois cadastrar em "Impressões digitais do certificado SHA" no painel do seu projeto Firebase (imagem).

Use o utilitário keytool para recuperar o SHA-1:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

[image: Print do painel Firebase]

Comment: Estava na documentação e eu não percebi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.